# angular.copy not working for the fields which depends on another (when using ng-change)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm having an issue with angular.copy in my scenario. I have a form with certain fields like name, mobile, state, district, city etc. When the user selects state, the districts will be retrieved accordingly. Same with the city. Here I'm using ng-change for the fields state and district. While adding the data, it is working fine. When editing the particular record, I'm using angular.copy. Then, only the fields which are independent like name, mobile, state are copying perfectly. But district and city are not getting copied. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Here is my HTML form.

```
<div ng-controller="EmpController">
 <form name="empForm" id="empForm" ng-submit="addEmp(emps)">
   Employee ID: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empid" name="empid" ng-model="emps.empid"  required /><br>

   Role: <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" ng-model="emps.role" ng-options="roles.role as roles.role for roles in rolelist" required>
             <option value="">Select</option>
         </select><br>
   State: <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" ng-model="data.state" ng-options="states.state as states.state for states in statelist" required ng-change="getDistricts(data.state)">
             <option value="">Select</option>
          </select><br>
   District: <select class="form-control" id="district" name="district" ng-model="data.district" ng-options="districts.district as districts.district for districts in districtlist" required ng-change="getCities(data)">
               <option value="">Select</option>
             </select><br>
   City: <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" ng-model="data.city" ng-options="cities.city as cities.city for cities in citylist" required ng-change="getAreas(data)">
           <option value="">Select</option>
         </select><br>
   Area: <select class="form-control" id="area" name="area" ng-model="data.area" ng-options="areas.area as areas.area for areas in arealist" required>
           <option value="">Select</option>
         </select><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add">
 </form>
 <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <th>Employee ID</th>
     <th>Role</th>
     <th>State</th>
     <th>District</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Area</th>
     <th>Action</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="emps in emplist">
       <td>{{emps.empid}}</td>
       <td>{{emps.role}}</td>
       <td>{{emps.state}}</td>
       <td>{{emps.district}}</td>
       <td>{{emps.city}}</td>
       <td>{{emps.area}}</td>
       <td>
         <button class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-click="editEmp(emps,$index);"></button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="deleteEmp(emps._id,$index);" style="margin-left:10px;" ng-if="emps.empid.toLowerCase()!='admin'"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here is my controller.js

```
app.controller("EmpController", function($scope, EmpService, RoleService, StateService, DistrictService, CityService, AreaService) {
$scope.rolelist=RoleService.getRole();
$scope.emplist=EmpService.getEmp();
$scope.statelist=StateService.getState();
$scope.getDistricts=function(state) {
    $scope.districtlist=DistrictService.getDistricts(state);
}
$scope.getCities=function(sds) {
    $scope.citylist=CityService.getCities(sds);
}
$scope.getAreas=function(list){
    $scope.arealist=AreaService.getAreas(list);
}
$scope.editEmp=function(id,index){
    $scope.emps=angular.copy(id);
    flag=index;
}
$scope.addEmp=function(emp){
    $scope.emps.pronarea=$scope.pronarealist;
    if(!$scope.emps._id){
        console.log(emp);
        EmpService.addEmp(emp);
        $scope.emps={};
    }
    else{
        EmpService.updateEmp(emp,flag);
    }
}
$scope.deleteEmp=function(id,index){
    EmpService.deleteEmp(id,index);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, After copying the object, you will get state, now based on state, get the districts and assign that to your list like

```
 $scope.editEmp=function(id,index){
$scope.emps=angular.copy(id);
  $scope.districtlist=DistrictService.getDistricts(id.state);
 //some stuff here to get the cities based on the district you get if match then get the city from below code 
  $scope.citylist=CityService.getCities(id.city);
flag=index;
}
```

Later assign those values to your model